# File sending Via Java

Tags: java, file, copy

My code is:

```
public class RemotePlay {

static final String USER_NAME = "bwisniewski";
static final String PASSWORD = "xxx";
static final String NETWORK_FOLDER = "smb://192.168.1.141/ADMIN$/";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String fileContent = "This is a test File";

    new RemotePlay().copyFiles(fileContent, "testFile1.txt");



}

public boolean copyFiles(String fileContent, String fileName) {
    boolean successful = false;

    try{
        String user = USER_NAME + ":" + PASSWORD;

        System.out.println("User: "+user);

        NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication(user);
        String path = NETWORK_FOLDER + fileName;
        System.out.println("Path: "+path);

        SmbFile sFile = new SmbFile(path, auth);

        SmbFileOutputStream sfos = new SmbFileOutputStream(sFile);
        sfos.write(fileContent.getBytes());

        successful = true;
        System.out.println("Successful "+successful);


    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        successful = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return successful;
}}
```

How can I change it to send exe file to ADMIN$ share. I prefer to use this method because I have to authenticate to remote pc. If you got better ideas to copy file to ADMIN$ share I am looking forward to hear about it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
sfos.write(fileContent.getBytes());
```

if your data is text, then why not to use PrintWriter to write down your file

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {    // temporary    
    File fileOne = new File("testfile1.txt");
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fileOne);

    // write down data
    writer.println("This is a test File");

    // free resources
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

and about the extension, you can use any extension you want while creating the file, it will still hold the data, and can be opened if you renamed it to the correct extension on the hard drive

if you named your file testfile.exe it will still hold your data, but when you double click it it wont work until you rename it to testfile.txt (or it will work if the extension is compatible with the data in the file)

Comment: OK but i wont to copy a file from local machine to remote. File like setup.exe or music.mp3